# Use of articles in software documentation

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I have some questions about the use of articles in [the documentation of the Laravel framework](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections).

> The `chunk` method breaks **the** collection into multiple, smaller collections of a given size

Why is used the definite article before 'collection'? Is it considered as the specific collection that the method should be applied to? Ok. Then why is used the indefinite article in other similar descriptions like this:

> The `collapse` method collapses **a** collection of arrays into **a** single, flat collection

More examples:

> The `firstWhere` method returns the first element in the collection with **the** given key / value pair

Here it is used the definite article before 'given key / value pair'. But in the sentence below:

> The `where` method filters the collection by **a** given key / value pair

The indefinite one. Why?

The last question is from [the description of the definite article](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/definite-article-the):

> We use the definite article in front of a noun when we believe **the** listener/reader knows exactly what we are referring to

Why is used the definite article before 'listener/reade'? Do we suppose that the listener and reader are the hypothetical particular persons who are talking about something?

I'm confused. The search doesn't help. Explain to me pls

Comment: I think they are interchangeable in those contexts.

Comment: I think that the "Why?" here is answered by saying that this documentation was probably not written by a careful, professional technical writer, so the person (or people) who wrote this was not really trying to keep a consistent style of usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The following answer assumes some fluency in computer programming languages

In regards to the documentation referenced, I believe I was able to catch some of the intention. The intention is subtle and relates very specifically to software.

*I should also note that the author made some assumptions about the reader that they shouldn't have.*

When it comes to object oriented software, or software that defines classes with fields and methods, it is important to differentiate how methods are referenced.

Lets say I have a class `Car` with a method `accelerate`:

```
Car car = new Car();
car.accelerate();
```

When describing `accelerate`, technical documentation may refer to **any instance** of the class `Car` with "The method `accelerate` makes **the** car move" which can be interpreted as:

> The method `accelerate` when called any instance of `Car` makes that instance move

By using "the" the author is assuming the reader understands this

Now lets say that `Car` has another method `flash` that only works when the instance of `Car` has high-beams.

When describing `flash`, technical documentation may refer to a **specific instance** of the class `Car` with "The method `flash` makes **a** car flash its high-beams" which can be interpreted as:

> The method `flash`, when called on a specific instance of `Car` that has high-beams, makes that instance flash it's high-beams

Comment: That is, in the first case with `accelerate` we don't know exactly what an instance we are talking about (any instance or that instance which the method is called on). Therefore we use **the** with car. In the second case with `flash` we know what the instance we mean and we can use **a** with car. But in the second case we can also use **the**. Right?

Comment: I think you are right, and it is just a matter of style. IMHO, I would not use the documentation you shared to learn technical writing. If anyone finds a good example of technical writing, please edit the answer with a reference! I think it would be helpful